# Infinispan cache entities are lost in production

Tags: java, caching, infinispan

We have infinispan cache with config (CustomCacheMaxCount is 100000):
`new ConfigurationBuilder().clustering() .partitionHandling().mergePolicy(MergePolicy.REMOVE_ALL) .clustering() .cacheMode(CacheMode.INVALIDATION_SYNC) .statistics().enable() .memory() .maxCount(cacheSettingsHolder.getCustomCacheMaxCount()) .whenFull(EvictionStrategy.REMOVE)`
After the last redeployment with some updates we noticed too slow responses. We found out that infinispan does not work properly.
We have no evictions and cluster partitioning.
[image]
But we have more misses than hits
[image]
And cache size is changing. Growing and decreasing, although it shouldn't decrease because there wasn't any eviction. While L2 cache works just fine.
[image]
[image]

Any ideas how to find the reason of this behavior and stop this cache from losing entries?

Comment: The reason is described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77318303/infinispan-cache-entities-are-lost-in-production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to use

```
Cache#putForExternalRead
```

to prevent cache on other nodes from invalidation after `Cache#put`